# List from SQLite in a preferences.xml

Tags: android, android-preferences

i'm a new android developer and i hope that you guys could help me.
I'm developing a preference screen like above:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/security_title" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:name="Password"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:key="passwordPref"
        android:password="true"
        android:summary="@string/security_sumary"
        android:title="@string/security_addPassword" />

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="secondPrefScreenPref"
        android:summary="Click here to go to the second Preference Screen"
        android:title="Second Preference Screen" >

        <ListPreference android:entries="@android:id/list" android:key="listPasswordKey" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

In a password field,the user are going to type his passw and when he clicks OK button, the program are gonna save it in my database. This part is ok!

But when he clicks on a second pref screen i want to list, from database, all your passwords saved.

I know how to load the data, but i don't know how to call my method when the user clicks on a SecondPrefScreen and how to show them in a preferences.xml

can anyone help me?

thx

Comment: Before I answer you, why, for the love of anything, would you want to save a password when it can so easily be viewed by the world?!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a widget that will load the data and list it for you. Essentially, create an object that extends [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) and give it a child list view that will list your security credentials.

Comment: tHX for answering and sorry for the long time. just these days i can return and put hands on again.
anyway, i've just searched a lot and didn't found how to implement you idea. can you give me a hint?